# How do we match any single character including line feed in Perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, text, pcre, ultraedit

I would like to use UltraEdit regular expression (perl) to replace the following text with some other text in a bunch of html files:

```
<style type="text/css">

#some-id{}

.some-class{}

//many other css styles follow

</style>
```

I tried to use `<style type="text/css">.*</style>` but of course it wouldn't match anything because the dot matches any character except line feed. I would like to match line feed as well and the line feed maybe either `\r\n` or `\n`.

How should the regular expression look like?

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In UltraEdit, you need to prepend `(?s)` to your regex to make the dot match newline.

I. e., search for

```
(?s)<style type="text/css">.*?</style>
```

I've also made the quantifier lazy (`.*?`) because otherwise you would match everything from the first `<style>` to the last `</style>` in your entire file.

Also be advised that this is a flaky solution because regular expressions can't parse HTML reliably if at all. In UltraEdit, that's all you have - a scripting language and a parser would be better, but if it works in your case, then great. Just make sure you don't match more (or less) than you wanted (think `//comment containing a </style> tag`).

Comment: @redDevil: The first sentence of my answer explains it: This modifier allows the dot to match newline characters (which it doesn't by default). See also Amarghosh's answer and the tutorial linked therein.

Answer (score 6):

Normally dot `.` matches all characters other than new line. Use the `s` [modifier in the regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) to force dot to match all characters including new line.